# GTX 1070 Ti no image when monitor connected to Display Port output

Tags: hdmi, gpu, displayport

I have used the Gigabyte GTX 1070 Ti with two Samsung F2080 monitors for a long time. One is plugged into DVI port, the other into the HDMI. Yesterday I thought it would be great to have the 3rd monitor, so I got a used Samsung P2050 which is working perfectly, but the 1070 has only DisplayPort outputs left. So I picked up a DP to HDMI converter and plugged in the 3rd monitor. But there is no image. If I switch a 2080 with the 2050 I get picture on 2050 and no picture on 2080.

The 3rd monitor does not show up in Nvidia Control Panel either. Also in the PhysX section where GPU back panel is shown, only 2 monitor connections are shown -- DVI and HDMI. The DP cable is fully plugged in all the way with a click. I tried all types of power cycles, rebooting with DP port plugged in -- to no avail. The strange thing however, if I keep the Samsung 2050 plugged into DP, the computer starts to lag, audio/video sync goes bad on Youtube etc. If I unplug the monitor from the DP socket, all goes back to normal. It looks as though the videocard is trying to set up a connection with the monitor but fails to do so. The "No signal" message also disappears from the monitor when it is plugged into the DP.

What should I do? The DP to monitor link goes thru a number of converters, DP->HDMI, then HDMI-DVI (since monitor has only DVI sockets). Should I buy a direct DP->DVI cable, would that work? I also read something about DP converter versions, there's 1.0 and 1.2, but how do I differentiate between them and know which one I need?

Answer (score 0):

It was the cabling! Just purchased a direct DVI -> DisplayPort cable, plugged it in, immediately heard the "New device detected" tone, and the 3rd monitor is working!